# Specialize a defined type in a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

For example

```
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef int Type;
    void f();
}
```

`Foo<T>::f()` can be specialized for a specific `T`. How about the defined type `Type`?  If it works, I don't need to specialize the whole class. Any ways to implement this intent?

Comment: What intent? EXPRESS your intent. Use few more words to express it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct Foo
{
  typedef typename some_class_template<T>::type Type;
  void f();
};
```

member functions have declaration and definition and you can specialise the definition. That cannot be done for member types. These must be specialised with their declaration.

Of course, my `some_class_template` can be anything from the standard library, for example

```
  typedef typename std::conditional<sizeof(T)==4, int, T>::type Type;
```

Comment: Very smart. To do it, I don't need to specialize the whole class.

Comment: @user1899020 Yes, that is the main method to avoid specialisations: inherit from or use simple specialised classes/methods, such as `std::conditional` or `std::enable_if`